# Extending a community extension not picking up my class

Tags: magento-enterprise, extensions, overrides

So I am trying to override an extension that we installed from MagentoConnect. Its just a tiny little nuance but its important to our plans. So this is what I have so far.

```
Blizzardlabs/Block/Affiliateplusext.php

class Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext_Block_Affiliateplusext extends Magestore_Affiliatepluscoupon_Block_Affiliatepluscoupon {

  public function getListProgram() {die();
    $listProgram = array();
    if (floatval($this->_getConfigHelper()->getGeneralConfig('discount')) >= 0) {
      $listProgram['default'] = new Varien_Object(array(
          'name' => $this->__('Affiliate Program'),
          'commission_type' => $this->_getConfigHelper()->getGeneralConfig('commission_type'),
          'commission' => $this->_getConfigHelper()->getGeneralConfig('commission'),
          'discount_type' => $this->_getConfigHelper()->getGeneralConfig('discount_type'),
          'discount' => $this->_getConfigHelper()->getGeneralConfig('discount'),
          'coupon_code' => $this->getAccount()->getCouponCode()
      ));
    }
    if ($this->isMultiProgram()) {
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('affiliateplusprogram/program_collection')
              ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
      $programCoupons = Mage::registry('program_coupon_codes');
      foreach ($collection as $item) {
        if ($item->getStatus() && isset($programCoupons[$item->getId()])) {
          $item->setCouponCode($programCoupons[$item->getId()]);
          $listProgram[$item->getId()] = $item;
        }
      }
    }
    return $listProgram;
  }

}
```

Here is my configuration

```
Blizzardlabs/etc/config.xml

<config>
  <modules>
    <Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <affiliatepluscoupon>
        <rewrite>
          <coupon>Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext_Block_Affiliateplusext</coupon>
        </rewrite>        
      </affiliatepluscoupon>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Here is my module declaration:

```
app/etc/modules/Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext.xml

<config>
    <modules>
        <Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
              <Magestore_Affiliatepluscoupon />
            </depends>
        </Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext>        
    </modules>
</config>
```

So, I am calling a  on the original module in the module declaration. I THINK im overwriting it correctly in my config and im also extending the original class in my class. Yet it refuses to pick it up. I have a feeling my issue is in my configuration. I think I am overriding it wrong there but I am not sure how. This is my first time so I apologize if its glaringly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was pretty simple. In config.xml my code needed to be like this:

```
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <affiliatepluscoupon>
        <rewrite>
          <affiliatepluscoupon>Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext_Block_Affiliateplusext</affiliatepluscoupon>
        </rewrite>        
      </affiliatepluscoupon>
    </blocks>
  </global>
```

I was going off of a helper call ('affiliatecouponplus/coupon') when this is a block. When thinking about it logically this made sense. I changed this and it is working fine now. I will add this as the answer when I can.